# setting routes for modifying profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to understand how to set new routes, however what I have chosen doesn't work and it just shows a "No route matches [GET] "/users/18/settings"".

What I would like to do is create a /settings that will display all the information users entered on the register page /users/new and shown on /users/ID/edit

routes.rb:

```
 Dating::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"
  get "profile/:id/settings" => 'users#edit'
  get 'settings', on: :member
  match 'settings' => 'users#settings'

  resources :users do
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :galleries
  resources :photos

  root to: 'users#new'
  root to: 'galleries#index'
```

end
end

rake routes:

settings_user GET    /users/:id/settings(.:format)       users#settings
                GET    /users(.:format)                    users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)                    users#create
                GET    /users/new(.:format)                users#new
                GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)           users#edit
                GET    /users/:id(.:format)                users#show
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                users#destroy
           root        /                                   users#new

```
   settings        /settings(.:format)                 users#settings
      users GET    /users(.:format)                    users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)                    users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                users#new
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)           users#edit
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                users#show
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                users#destroy
   sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)                 sessions#index
            POST   /sessions(.:format)                 sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)             sessions#new
```

edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)        sessions#edit
        session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)             sessions#show
                PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)             sessions#update
                DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)             sessions#destroy

Comment: Could you do either
`get 'settings' => 'settings#whatever'` 
   or 
`resources :settings`.
Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Could you, please, provide output of ```rake routes```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
resources :users do  
    get 'settings', on: :member  
end
```

for */users/18/settings*
and

```
match 'settings' => 'users#settings'
```

for */settings*.

Comment: And they can also do `get` instead of `match` if they wanted to map it only to `GET` requests.

Comment: Provides uninitialized constant UserController error when doing the get 'settings' with resources :users do.

Comment: @pwz2000 Are you certain you spelled it :users and not :user in the routing file? Also, regarding the `match` line Sergey wrote, the controller/action mapping should be `users#settings` if your controller is pluralized (meaning, it is called UsersController).

Comment: I C&P what he wrote, and fixed the 'user' to 'users'. Neither method work for /users/18/settings and /settings. I just get "No route matches [GET] "/users/18/settings"" I updated original post with how my routes look with the code.

Comment: @pwz2000 OK I see your edit. I think you got a little mixed up, syntax-wise. Put the `get 'settings', on: :member` line underneath the `resources :users do`, which should be followed by `end`. I've edited Sergey's answer to include more obvious spacing. That should hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks it works now for users/18/settings. /settings gives me a "Couldn't find User without an ID" error. In users controller I have " @user = User.find(params[:id])". Do I need more than that?

Comment: @pwz2000 Right, yes you'd need to have the URL accept an ID parameter.  So your match line would look something like `match 'settings/:id`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything works the way I want. I expected routes to be quicker to understand.